# Math regex express route

Tags: regex, express, routes, express-router

I'm tring to filter a route with param, but no success. I have 2 routes:

```
/all
/:id
```

I'm using [typescript-rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-rest) to dynamic load, so there's no way to add the all route first.

```
Server.loadServices(this.appWebApi, 'app/resources/*.js', `${__dirname}`);
```

I have this 2 methods:

```
@GET
@Path("all")
async all(@Context context: ServiceContext) {}

@GET
@Path(":id")
async findById(@Context context: ServiceContext, @PathParam("id") id: string) {}
```

But both is called when i use `/all`. I tried to use `^(?!all):id` but the parameter is not working.

So, how to filter this 2 routes?

Comment: Did you put them in this order?

Comment: Yes, so as it didn't work, I tried to filter the url

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, the problem is related to typescript-rest package.

Here the proposed solution:

https://github.com/thiagobustamante/typescript-rest/issues/78#issuecomment-469232775